# Set an ASP.NET HyperLink NavigateUrl to a relative path?

Tags: asp.net, url

When you try to set a HyperLink Control's `NavigateUrl` property to a relative path, e.g.:

```
pages/myPage.aspx
```

ASP.NET will resolve the relative URL to an absolute one.

How do I get a proper relative URL in the generated HTML?

Interestingly, relative URLs with a leading slash, *are* rendered as-is, without being resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `NavigateUrl`, set the Control's `href` attribute:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" href="pages/myPage.aspx">test</asp:HyperLink>
```

or in code-behind:

```
myHyperLinkId.Attributes["href"] = "pages/myPage.aspx";
```

Comment: Can you show us what you get for both methods (NavigateUrl and href)? When I test it, I see the same URL in the HTML output of the page. As for getting a path relative to the application root folder, I can get it with the `NavigateUrl="~/pages/myPage.aspx"` syntax.

Comment: You seem to be correct… I am currently unable to reproduce the problems I was originally encountering. I will investigate more soon, and I'll hopefully be able to update my Q and or A when I have more information.

Comment: I updated my question. You were right about the specific relative URL I used. The problem only occurs when using relative URLs that don't start with a slash or period(s).